# jQuery Mobile label misalignment for blank HTML5 date field on ios7 (iPad)

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, jquery-mobile, datepicker

Wow - just looking at that title makes me realize what an obscure error this is, but hey, let's go with it.  Anyone experiencing the same thing or have any suggestions on how to correct this?  Visual explanation is probably best.

Stack:

- jQuery 1.9.1
- jQuery Mobile 1.3.2
- Desktop browser:  Chrome 31.0.1650.39 beta (OSX Mavericks)
- Mobile browser:  Both Safari & Chrome on iOS 7.0.3

Super basic code:

```
<label for="customer_date_of_birth">Date of birth</label>
<input id="customer_date_of_birth" name="customer[date_of_birth]" size="30" type="date" />
```

Le Problems:

Desktop (looking good) -

[image]

Mobile w/ blank input (bleh) -

[image]

Mobile, as soon as I select a date (back to looking good) -

[image]

I haven't a clue how to debug this, since all of my debugging tools are on the desktop and this problem only shows up on my iPad.

Any thoughts, oh people-who-are-better-at-this-than-I ?  (Thanks!)

Comment: Post more code please, i.e. parent div.

Answer (score 1):

See the reference [here](http://demo.hongkiat.com/html5-form-input-type/index1.html)

Your CSS for type=date should be changed as below:

```
{ 
align-items: center;
display: -webkit-inline-flex; 
overflow: hidden; 
padding: 0px; 
-webkit-padding-start: 1px; 
}
```